# unable to have my tezbox wallet be "revealed"

Tags: wallets

I recovered my tokens from the fundraiser today on Tezbox. I see the funds in the wallet and I was even able to transfer tezzies from coinbase in to the wallet. I cant send any out because it

Comment: Tezbox is no longer maintained. Please mive to an alternative wallet thank you. (Check Galleon, Kukai or Ledger Live eg)

Answer (score 1):

No, it is actually very useful. You can export your private key from Tezbox and then use that with any other wallet. Here's a <1 min. video on how to migrate from using Tezbox to Galleon: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fLnOcezCZU0&feature=youtu.be

This will solve your problem.

Comment: Please mark this is as the proper answer if you feels it's answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm stupid but I'm pretty sure Sergio said he could not move his XTZ?
So, "please move to alternative" probably has limited usefulness.
I'm sharing the same problem as Sergio here.
It seems Tezbox is no longer maintained?